# Pass content of large files from standard Logic apps to API apps

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I am using ASP.NET Web API project with Swashbuckle to test a simple custom API app that accepts 2 parameters: file name and file content.

```
public class Parm
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger:

```
{
  "FileName": "string",
  "FileContent": "string"
}
```

I have an issue integrating this API app with **Logic app**s, e.g. process all files created in OneDrive folder as follows:

1. "When a file is created" trigger in OneDrive
2. Call the custom API app with parameters `File name` and `File content` from the previous step.

As long as uploaded files are relatively small everything works fine, however for larger files (e.g. 10 MB) `FileContent` is received as null, and the logic of the process understandably fails.

Any idea what can be the reason of the problem? I've tried changing `FileContent` from `string` to other types (`Stream`, etc.), however that wouldn't work. Only following parameters from the previous step are available: `File content`, `File content type`, `File entity tag`, `File identifier`, `File name` and `File path`.

Standard API's such as "Azure Blob Storage - Create blob", etc. don't have any issue processing large `File content` so there surely must be a way to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by increasing the value of the `HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength` property in the API app's Web.config:

```
<configuration>  
    <system.web>  
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="12288" />  
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

[Default value is 4096 KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx).